# Yearling Badge calculation not working on my Meta profile

Tags: support, reputation, badges, yearling-badge, reputation-recalc

I've read the other questions about receiving the Yearling badge, but none seem to fit my question.
I have been a [member for 1 year and 8 months at this point, and currently have rep of 216](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130071/kevin-worthington) and yet I have not 'earned' the Yearling badge.
I tried to [recalculate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation) but still nothing. Any ideas? Thanks for your time.

Comment: When did you pass 200 points? Badge scripts are run on varying schedules so it could be that the `Yearling` badge script hasn't run yet.

Comment: [It looks like I passed 200 on January 23rd.](http://twitpic.com/4ad3rt/full)

Comment: When did you associate your accounts, if I may inquire? How long ago did you receive the +100 association bonus? Also, that page can actually viewed by other users now.

Comment: I'm not sure when the accounts were associated. I remember it being quite a long time ago. Is there some way I can check that?

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Comment: Bump: I've also passed the 200 rep mark on SO, and no Yearling badge there either FWIW.